# CoCreateInstanceEx returns S_OK with invalid credentials on Win2003

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am writing a client app that gets connected remotely to a server. I need to impersonate the user my client will work with.

This is the excerpt of my code:

```
COAUTHIDENTITY coAuthIdentity, *pCoAuthIdentity;
COAUTHINFO coAuthInfo;

CComBSTR bstrDomain(domain), bstrServer(server);
CComBSTR bstrUser(user), bstrPassword(password);
CComBSTR bstrServerPrincName(domain);
bstrServerPrincName.Append(L"\\");
bstrServerPrincName.Append(server);

coAuthIdentity.Flags    = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;
coAuthIdentity.Domain   = (USHORT *)bstrDomain.m_str;
coAuthIdentity.DomainLength = bstrDomain.Length();
coAuthIdentity.Password = (USHORT *)bstrPassword.m_str;
coAuthIdentity.PasswordLength   = bstrPassword.Length();
coAuthIdentity.User     = (USHORT *)bstrUser.m_str;
coAuthIdentity.UserLength   = bstrUser.Length();
pCoAuthIdentity         = &coAuthIdentity;
*ppCoAuthIdentity       = pCoAuthIdentity;

coAuthInfo.dwAuthnSvc       = RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT;  // Have COM negotiate the best authentication service
coAuthInfo.dwAuthzSvc       = RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE;
coAuthInfo.pwszServerPrincName  = bstrServerPrincName;

coAuthInfo.dwAuthnLevel     = RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT;
coAuthInfo.dwImpersonationLevel = RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE;
coAuthInfo.pAuthIdentityData    = &coAuthIdentity;
coAuthInfo.dwCapabilities       = EOAC_NONE;

COSERVERINFO coServerInfo;
::memset(&coServerInfo, 0, sizeof(COSERVERINFO));

coServerInfo.pwszName    = bstrServer;
coServerInfo.dwReserved1 = 0;
coServerInfo.pAuthInfo   = &coAuthInfo;
coServerInfo.dwReserved2 = 0;

MULTI_QI multiQI = { &__uuidof(IServer), 0, 0 };

TCHAR name [MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
DWORD size = sizeof(name);
DWORD dwServer = CLSCTX_SERVER;
if (::GetComputerName(name, &size) != 0)
{
    if (_wcsicmp(name, coServerInfo.pwszName))
            dwServer = CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER;
    else
        dwServer = CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER;
}
else
{
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
}    

hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(
    __uuidof(IServer),
        NULL,
    dwServer,
    &coServerInfo,
    1,
    &multiQI);
```

My problem occurs when I have my client and my server installed in the same computer. In Windows 2003, when I pass the credentials of any user (valid or invalid) to my server, the CoCreateInstanceEx function always returns S_OK.

The problem is that the user being used in the server side is not the impersonated one, but the user that launched my client process.

Using Windows 2008 this works properly. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa913628.aspx

Maybe using registry values instead of explicit auth values?  CoInitializeSecurity being called elsewhere?  Only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

The [Don Box - Essential COM](https://books.google.no/books/about/Essential_COM.html?id=kfRWvKSePmAC) book states: "*at the time of this writing, COAUTHIDENTITY is not supported for same-machine communications*" (p.289). Also, the [Thuan Thai - Learning DCOM](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925816.do) book states: "*setting the authentication identity will apply only when the client and server components run on different machines*" (chap. 9 - Client-Side Security).

I therefore suspect that your same-machine problem is caused by a long standing Windows limitation. I'm also able to reproduce the problem on Windows 10 (version 1803).